# Print/plot string objects in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to print calendar month wise as shown in the bottom figure. I use following lines to generate calendar

```
import calendar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# key represents year and values represents required months
cal = {2013: range(11,13),2014: range(1,13), 2015: range(1,9)}
result = []
for key,value in cal.items():
  year = key
  months = value
  for month in months:
    result.append(calendar.month(year,month))
```

Now, each month is stored as a string object in the result object. To print months in Grid format I use following lines:

```
f,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=8,ncols=3)
for row in ax:
  for col in row:
    plt.text(result[row+col])
```

I think I need to use some other function instead of `plt.text()`. Do I need to change this function or I have to add some other lines? 
[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to tell what exactly you are trying to achieve. `plt.text` needs to take the coordinates of where to place the text, as well as the string to show as input, `plt.text(x,y,"text")`. Apart, I don't know what you want.